# Scroll event background change

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am trying to add a scroll event which will change the background of a div which also acts as the window background (it has 100% width and height). This is as far as I get. I am not so good at jquery. I have seen tutorials with click event listeners. but applying the same concept , like, returning scroll event as false, gets me nowhere. also I saw a tutorial on SO where the person suggest use of array. but I get pretty confused using arrays (mostly due to syntax).

I know about plugins like `waypoints.js` and `skrollr.js` which can be used but I need to change around 50-60 (for the illusion of a video being played when scrolled) ... but it wont be feasible.

here is the code im using:-

```
*
{
    border: 2px solid black;
}

#frame
{
    background: url('1.jpg') no-repeat;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
}

</style>
```

```
<script>

$(function(){

for ( i=0; i = $.scrolltop; i++)
{
    $("#frame").attr('src', ''+i+'.jpg');
}

});

</script>

<body>

<div id="frame"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: You want the background of the `div` scrolled when you scroll your mouse or you want this background change like a image chains (24 image / second? )?

Comment: i dont want the <code>div</code> scrolled .. i want it to stay stationary ... but the background of the div should change .. when th user scrolls ... for example at every 10px scrolled , the image should change..

Answer (score 1):

Inside your for loop, you are setting the `src` attribute of `#frame` but it is a `div` not an `img`.

So, instead of this:

```
$("#frame").attr('src', ''+i+'.jpg');
```

Try this:

```
$("#frame").css('background-image', 'url(' + i + '.jpg)');
```

To bind a scroll event to a target **`element`** with jQuery:

```
$('#target').scroll(function() {
    //do stuff here
});
```

To bind a scroll event to the **`window`** with jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    //do stuff here
});
```

Here is the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) for jQuery `.scroll()`.

**UPDATE:**

If I understand right, here is a **[working demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/ckHuF/)** of what you want to achieve.

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    min-height: 1200px; /* for testing the scroll bar */
}

div#frame {
    display: block;
    position: fixed; /* Set this to fixed to lock that element on the position */
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: -1; /* Keep the bg frame at the bottom of other elements. */
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    switchImage();
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    switchImage();
});

//using images from dummyimages.com for demonstration (300px by 300px)
var images = ["http://dummyimage.com/300x300/000000/fff", 
              "http://dummyimage.com/300x300/ffcc00/000",
              "http://dummyimage.com/300x300/ff0000/000",
              "http://dummyimage.com/300x300/ff00cc/000",
              "http://dummyimage.com/300x300/ccff00/000"
             ];

//Gets a valid index from the image array using the scroll-y value as a factor.
function switchImage()
{
    var sTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var index = sTop > 0 ? $(document).height() / sTop : 0;
    index = Math.round(index) % images.length;
    //console.log(index);
    $("#frame").css('background-image', 'url(' + images[index] + ')');
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="frame"></div>
```

**Further Suggestions:**

I suggest you change the `background-image` of the **body**, instead of the div. But, if you **have to** use a `div` for this; then you better add a **resize** event-istener to the `window` and set/update the height of that div with every resize. The reason is; `height:100%` does not work as expected in any browser.

Comment: <script>
 $("#frame").scroll(function(){
  
  var i = $(this).scrollTop();
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + i*100 + '.jpg)');
 
 });

</script>

Comment: The `scroll` event is fired when an element have a scrollbar. The `div` without scrollbar never fire this event.

Comment: Your demo will not work when the window does not have the vertical scrollbar :)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before myself and if I were you I wouldn't use the image as a background, instead use a normal "img" tag prepend it to the top of your page use some css to ensure it stays in the back under all of the other elements. This way you could manipulate the size of the image to fit screen width better. I ran into a lot of issues trying to get the background to size correctly.

Html markup:

```
<body>
<img src="1.jpg" id="img" />
</body>
```

Script code:

```
$(function(){

    var topPage = 0, count = 0;

    $(window).scroll( function() {
        topPage = $(document).scrollTop();

        if(topPage > 200) {
           // function goes here
           $('img').attr('src', ++count +'.jpg');
        } 
    });
});
```

I'm not totally sure if this is what you're trying to do but basically, when the window is scrolled, you assign the value of the distance to the top of the page, then you can run an if statement to see if you are a certain point. After that just simply change run the function you would like to run.

If you want to supply a range you want the image to change from do something like this, so what will happen is this will allow you to run a function only between the specificied range between 200 and 400 which is the distance from the top of the page.

```
$(function(){

    var topPage = 0, count = 0;

    $(window).scroll( function() {
        topPage = $(document).scrollTop();

        if(topPage > 200 && topPage < 400) {
           // function goes here
           $('#img').attr('src', ++count +'.jpg');
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: okay so how did you manage to change the image with scroll event?

Comment: Also you could place this code in order to resize the img, this will check the window width and height and resize the image, it will also change anytime the window is changed although I would only resize the width in order to keep the img's aspect ratio:

<code>
$(window).resize( function () {
   $('#img').width($(window).width()).height($(window).height());
});
</code>

Comment: in a way i am trying to reproduce this site <a href="http://a-class.mercedes-benz.com/com/en/?prefv=d">http://a-class.mercedes-benz.com/com/en/?prefv=d</a>